# Format custom summary output to match with ANOVA output in R

Tags: r, summary, anova

I'm new to R. We have an assignment that i'm working on. The assignment is on creating R package to mimic Anova table. I have created all the necessary function that is mandated in the assignment. The function calculates the correct values, but I couldn't make it display like ANOVA table that R's built in anova() function can. This is my summary.oneway function

```
summary.oneway <- function(object, ...){

  #model <- oneway(object)
  fval <- object$FValue
  TAB <- list(t(object$AOV), "Mean Sq."= rbind(object$MSB, object$MSW),
              "F Value" = fval, p.value = object$p.value)

  res <- list(call=object$call, onewayAnova = TAB)
  class(res) <- "summary.oneway"
  res  
}
```

This is the output:

```
Analysis of Variance:
oneway.formula(formula = coag ~ diet, data = coagdata)

[[1]]
         Sum of Squares Deg. of Freedom
diet                228               3
Residual            112              20

$`Mean Sq.`
        1
[1,] 76.0
[2,]  5.6

$`F Value`
       1 
13.57143 

$p.value
           1 
4.658471e-05
```

Actual ANOVA output:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: coag
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
diet       3    228    76.0  13.571 4.658e-05 ***
Residuals 20    112     5.6                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

How can I achieve this format? Where and what am I missing?

Thank you so much for your help.

Kuni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Anova output uses the print method `print.anova`  you may want to take look at `methods(print)`  and specifically `stats:::print.anova`

You will most likely want to create your own print function

```
 print.oneway <- function(object, ...) {
     foo
     bar
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I do have the print function like you have mentioned, but it was still printing the list. I used the printCoefmat() and provided data.frame as argument, and it worked fine.

Comment: Glad it helped.  You can also modify the `class(obj)` so that the appropriate `print` method is used.